# iOS sharing 'global data' across view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, sharing

I have been using app delegate as a "global bucket" to share data between various view controllers.  Typically I do something like this:

```
My_AppDelegate *appDelegate = (My_AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And then, I would stick data into the appDelegate, and pick up data from the appDelegate with another view controller.  Somehow, this seems clumsy and inappropriate (although it does work).

Is there a better way?  Can I set-up a "listener" on some kind of a global sharing area, if somebody sticks a data element in there, another object would get a 'call-back' to let it know that somebody has data ready for it?

In Java we used to do this with Observer/Observable class - maybe there is something like this, or better in iOS?

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner, although not necessarily different, way to do this is to create a singleton class, e.g. `AppData`, which you can access in a variety of ways, and which would be available to all your other classes. It has the benefit of separating your app-specific stuff from the app delegate stuff. You might define the class this way:

```
@interface AppData : NSObject

// Perhaps you'll declare some class methods here...

@end
```

A common thing I do is define class methods on such a class to access, for example, settings values, or app-specific constants or other singleton objects. There are a lot of possibilities.

In the end, you can get a lot done with just class methods, that you would call something like `[AppData theMethod]`. Just remember there's no `self` to access inside a class method.

Taking it one step further, you can define ivars for the AppData class, and then manage a singleton instance of AppData. Use a class method, e.g. `+sharedInstance`, to get a handle to the singleton on which you could then call mehods. For example, `[[AppData sharedInstance] someMethod:myArgument]`. Your implementation of `+sharedInstance` can be where you manage the actual creation of the singleton, which the method ultimately returns.

I am not sure if I'd call this approach a "best practice", but I've found this pattern quite handy.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about singletons, and I use them in Java all the time..  I will try it..